# Accessing GPIO via MMIO in Android App on Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: android, gpio, raspberry-pi4

I'm currently developing an Android application aimed at managing GPIO pins on a Raspberry Pi 4 running the Android OS directly.

While I understand that Android operates within a sandboxed environment, potentially limiting access to certain filesystem directories, I'm investigating the feasibility of using /dev/gpiomem to directly map GPIO pins into memory.

My question is:

Is it feasible to employ Memory-Mapped I/O (MMIO) techniques within an Android application running on a Raspberry Pi 4 to interact with GPIO pins via /dev/gpiomem, utilizing native code? If not, are there alternative solutions available to access GPIO pins from my Android application?

Comment: As there is no official Android version for Raspberry everything depends on the ROM you use. To my knowledge on Linux usually programs without root permissions don't have write access to devices via `/dev/...` so you need some system service that runs with root permissions and provides an app access for apps using a specially designed API.

Comment: No-one should use GPIO behind OS' back like this.